# Parse json into html template

Tags: python, json, templates, bottle

I select a row from the database which has some json content

My function to select row

```
@route('/list')
def list():
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT content FROM pages WHERE URL = 'blob.com'")
    select = c.fetchall()
    return template('views/list.tpl', rows=select)
```

and result from row 'content' is:

```
{ "ruleGroups": { 
    "SPEED": { "score": 97 } 
                }, 
    "pageStats": { "numberResources": 3, 
                   "numberHosts": 2, 
                   "totalRequestBytes": "500", 
                   "imageResponseBytes": "3148", 
                   "otherResponseBytes": "3838" 
                 }, 
    "screenshot": { "mime_type": "image/jpeg", 
                    "data": "imgcontent", 
                    "width": 320, 
                    "height": 240, 
                  } 
}
```

I want to display in list.tpl from json "score", "numberResources" and "numberHosts".

How should I proceed in list.tpl?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, perhaps: `content['ruleGroups']['SPEED']['score']`; `content['pageStats']['numberResources']`; `content['pageStats']['numberHosts']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template do the folowing:

```
    % for row in rows:
        % for key, value in row.iteritems():
            %if key == 'ruleGroups':
                <p>SCORE: {{value['SPEED']['score']}}</p>
            %elif key == 'pageStats':
                <p>Number of resources: {{value['numberResources']}}</p>
                <p>Number of hosts: {{value['numberHosts']}}</p>
            %end
        %end
    %end
```